# Php: How can I get the same date of the following months, quarterly and semi-annually

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I'm this situation where users can choose to be billed either every month, quarter or semi-annual on one specific date the choose in a billing cycle. I'm using Laravel PHP framework.

Eg. Monthly - 5 May 2016, 5 June 2016, 5 July 2016, etc.
Billed on 5 on every month
Eg. Quarterly - 10 Jan 2016, 10 March 2016, 10 June 2016 etc...
Billed on 10 after every three months
Eg. Semi-Annually - 13 Apr 2016, 13 Sept 016
Billed on 13 after every six months.

The goal here is to get the same date on the every month the user choose to be billed, but in a month, quarterly or semi-annually.

This is my code after I play with @Rishi methode for some time

```
public function as_you_go($pay_as_you_go,$grand_total,$payment_date,$policy_id)
{
    $policy = $this->findorFail($policy_id);
    if($pay_as_you_go == 'Semi-Annually'){
        $payments_no = 2;
        $installment_amount = $grand_total/$payments_no;
        $month_gap = 6;
        $add_month = '+6 month';
    }elseif($pay_as_you_go == 'Quarterly'){
        $payments_no = 4;
        $installment_amount = $grand_total/$payments_no;
        $month_gap = 3;
        $add_month = '+3 month';
    }elseif($pay_as_you_go == 'Monthly'){
        $payments_no = 12;
        $installment_amount = $grand_total/$payments_no;
        $month_gap = 1;
        $add_month = '+1 month';
    }

    // Pay as you go calculations
    for ($x = 0; $x < $payments_no; $x++) {
        //$add_month = '+'.$x.' month';
        $installment = new \App\Installment;
        $installment->amount = $installment_amount;


        if(\App\Installment::wherePayableType('App\Policy')->wherePayableId($policy->id)->first()){

            $payment = \App\Installment::wherePayableType('App\Policy')->wherePayableId($policy->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
            $date = $payment->payment_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $installment->payment_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date.$add_month));
        }else{
            $installment->payment_date = $payment_date;
        }
        $installment->is_payed = 'No';
        $policy->installments()->save($installment);
    }

}
```

This is my function I wanted to generates dates according to user's date of choice based on semi-annual, quarterly and monthly payment gap.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post some code.. I mean attempt to find solution and only then ask.. this looks like "give me solution" kind of question which nobody here likes :)

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't have any kind of idea or code when posting this question, I had an only blank function, so I thought it not gonna help anybody. @otopolsky

Comment: hm you got ample of answers so it might be a good question after all :) I meant that when you show some code.. or at least "pseudocode" of what you want to achieve it will help people to understand what you want to achieve.. and at the same time you might find some solution by trying things.. it happened to me few times that when I was asking question.. then I though ok lets add some code.. and I wrote just little something - and it worked ! have a nice day..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
<?php
  $date = '1-may-2016';
  echo date('d-F-Y',strtotime($date.'+1 month'))."\n";
  echo date('d-F-Y',strtotime($date.'+3 month'))."\n";
  echo date('d-F-Y',strtotime($date.'+6 month'))."\n";
?>
```

check output here : https://eval.in/582424

Also you need to think about dates like `$date = '30-jan-2016';`.

Comment: already said he need to think about this, it will not give same date. Its verbally wrong if we says `same date for next month` not ?

Comment: Sorry didn't read that sentence in that way. Yes it should perhaps say same daynumber next month.

Comment: A tried you method Rishi with some few updates it worked fine. Thanks guys for the support.

Comment: @MichaelReuben I think you should post the code. It's part of SO. The answer is the most important. Others may find this thread later and want the code.

Comment: I added my working codes after I played with @Rishi method.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for, but I think the following will help you on your way.

You can use `DateTime` and `DateInterval` to manipulate dates to add on a number of months.

```
// We have a DateTime object which is on the 5th may
$date = new DateTime('2016-05-05');

$billingType = 'monthly';

switch ($billingType) {
    case 'monthly':
        $interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
        break;

    case 'quarterly':
        $interval = new DateInterval('P3M');
        break;

    case 'biannually':
        $interval = new DateInterval('P6M');
        break;
}

$newDate = clone $date;
$newDate->add($interval);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2016-05-05
echo $newDate->format('Y-m-d'); // 2016-06-05
```

Let's say that you wanted to check if today is the day to bill someone...

```
function isBillingDate(DateTime $date, DateTime $billingDate, $billingType)
{
    switch ($billingType) {
        case 'monthly':
            $interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
            break;

        case 'quarterly':
            $interval = new DateInterval('P3M');
            break;

        case 'biannually':
            $interval = new DateInterval('P6M');
            break;
    }

    $isBillingDate = false;

    $date->setTime(00, 00, 00);
    $billingDate->setTime(00, 00, 00);

    do {
        if ($date == $billingDate) {
            $isBillingDate = true;
        } else {
            $billingDate->add($interval);
        }
    } while ($isBillingDate === false && $date <= $billingDate);

    return $isBillingDate;
}

$date = new DateTime('now'); // We want to check if we should bill them today (3rd June)

$billingStartDate = new DateTime('2016-05-03'); // They signed up to get billed on the 3rd of May
$billingType = 'monthly'; // They want to get billed every month
var_dump(isBillingDate($date, $billingStartDate, $billingType)); // True

$billingStartDate = new DateTime('2016-03-03'); // They signed up to get billed on the 3rd of March
$billingType = 'quarterly'; // They want to get billed quarterly
var_dump(isBillingDate($date, $billingStartDate, $billingType)); // True

$billingStartDate = new DateTime('2016-04-03'); // They signed up to get billed on the 3rd of April
$billingType = 'quarterly'; // They want to get billed quarterly
var_dump(isBillingDate($date, $billingStartDate, $billingType)); // False
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code from Rishi I made this.
It splits the date to two parts and uses one to the month calculation and the other to the day.

Edit: noticed a quite obvious error in the code.

```
<?php
$date = '2016-01-26';
$date2= substr($date,0,7)."-01";
$period = "+3 month";

If(substr($date,-2) >  date('t',strtotime($date2.$period))){

    echo date('t-F-Y',strtotime($date2.$period))."\n";

}else{

    echo date("d-", strtotime($date)) . date('F-Y',strtotime($date2.$period))."\n";

}
?>
```

https://eval.in/582564

Output:

```
From 31 of january:
28-February-2016
30-April-2016
31-July-2016
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function iterateMonths(DateTime $date, $months = 1, $iterations = 12)
{
    $day = $date->format('d');

    for ($a = 0; $a < $iterations; $a++)
    {
        // Increment at least one month, but cap at the last day
        $date->modify("last day of next month");

        // Add on additional months if required
        if ($months > 1)
        {
            $mDiff = $months-1;
            $date->modify("+{$mDiff} months");
        }

        // If we are billing earlier than the last day of the month,
        // rewind that number of days
        if ($day < $date->format('d'))
        {
            $dDiff = $date->format('d') - $day;
            $date->modify("-{$dDiff} days");
        }

        echo $date->format('Y-m-d'), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

## Standard monthly billing

```
$date = new \DateTime('2016-06-03');
iterateMonths($date);
// 2016-07-03, 2016-08-03, 2016-09-03, etc
```

## Late days in months

```
$date = new \DateTime('2016-01-31');
iterateMonths($date, 1, 11);
// 2016-02-29, 2016-03-31, 2016-04-30, 2016-05-31
```

## Quarterly (for four quarters)

```
$date = new \DateTime('2016-07-14');
iterateMonths($date, 3, 4);

// 2016-10-14, 2017-01-14, 2017-04-14, 2017-07-14
```